# Excel: Computing a pvalue

Tags: p-value, excel

An event has an expected probability of .4. After 100 trials, the event occurred 30 times. How can the pvalue be computed in Excel?

Comment: You should specify a null and an alternative, and a test statistic. This reads like a textbook-type question. Is this for some class?

Comment: Not for a class as I finished education forty years ago. I'm just a guy with an Excel stat problem.

Comment: As I said, in order to compute a p-value, you should specify a null and an alternative, and a test statistic. Otherwise, there are multiple possible answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the BINOMDIST() function, with cumulative set to TRUE.  That gives you one tail (i.e. extreme in one direction). Double it for two tails (i.e. as extreme as this both above and below)